# FactoryClass vs a Normal Java Class

Tags: java, class, factory

Factory Class are like a `DriverManager.getConnection("...conn...")`. They are class methods of a class

Now, how are they different from Normal classes like the one in `java.lang.util`

By normal classes what i mean is that , whose instance are created like as follows.

```
Date d=new Date();
```

So what are factory classes compared to one mentioned Above(Date Class)?

Comment: It's very difficult to know what is asked here. What is the question (which is very difficult to determine without any question mark)?

Comment: What do you mean by "Normal"?  Factory classes are normal.  In fact there are factory classes inside of `java.lang.util` (Such as the `Collections` class.  Factory is a design pattern, FactoryClasses implement that design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are "normal" classes but they follow the **Factory method pattern**

[image: Factory example implementation]

The factory pattern is used to:

> - Create objects without exposing the instantiation logic to the client.
> - Refer to the newly created object through a common interface

From: http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html

Here's an example of how to do it in java

```
package designPatterns.creational.factory;

public class CarFactory {
    public static Car buildCar(CarType model) {
        Car car = null;
        switch (model) {
            case SMALL:
                    car = new SmallCar();
                    break;

            case SEDAN:
                    car = new SedanCar();
                    break;

            case LUXURY:
                    car = new LuxuryCar();
                    break;

            default:
                    // throw some exception
                    break;
            }
        return car;
    }
}
```

Complete example: http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/23/implementing-factory-design-pattern-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

The factory method you speak about is called a **Design Pattern**. The factory method is a creational pattern that prevents the hardcoding of constructors and is probably one of the most common Object Oriented Design Patterns. The key thing to realize here is that the Factory pattern designs an interface for creating objects. It promotes the **DRY principle** (Don't Repeat Yourself) by reducing the amount of duplicate code.

If your code needs to be portable, you will want to avoid hardcoding constructor calls in your application. Sometimes it is best to let the subclasses decide which class to instantiate.

You asked the difference between a Factory created object and an object created without one? They are both still objects and the class that you are invoking the factory method on behind the scenes is creating an object and returning it back to you. Some objects are so complex it just makes more sense to use a predefined interface to create the object. Lastly, sometimes information about creating an object should not be exposed to the user.